# Using the pkg-config macro PKG_CHECK_MODULES failing

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, autoconf, automake, pkg-config

I'm sure this is a fairly simple problem. I have a very simple configure.ac file which I am using to just learn how autoconf & pkg-config work together. The `confgure.ac` file looks like:

```
AC_PREREQ(2.61)
AC_INIT(autoconf_test, 1.0, nowhere@dev.null)

PKG_CHECK_MODULES(libusbmuxd, libusbmuxd >= 0.1.4)
```

I can then execute autoconf from the command line and it does produce a configure script. However, when I run the configure script, I get the following error:

```
./configure: line 1618: syntax error near unexpected token `libusbmuxd,'
./configure: line 1618: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(libusbmuxd, libusbmuxd >= 0.1.4)'
```

If I use the pkg-config program from the command line to check to see whether it can find this library, it succeeds.

```
/usr/lib/pkgconfig $pkg-config --libs --cflags --modversion libusbmuxd

1.0.7
-I/usr/local/Cellar/usbmuxd/1.0.7/include  -L/usr/local/Cellar/usbmuxd/1.0.7/lib -lusbmuxd
```

So, it seems clear that for some reason the `PGK_CHECK_MODULE` macro cannot be located and I am not sure why.

This probably isn't OS specific, but I am using Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: The macro is in a file `pkg.m4` if I'm not wrong. Can you find this file somewhere in `/usr/share/aclocal` or a similar directory?

Comment: Use 'aclocal --print' to determine the directory in which to look for pkg.m4

Comment: How did you install pkg-config, and how did you install the autotools?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you are bootstrapping (ie, running autoreconf), aclocal is unable to find pkg.m4.  This is because pkg-config was either not installed or has been installed somewhere that aclocal does not know about.  (ie, it was installed with a different prefix than automake.)  To solve this, you need to find where `pkg-config` installed `pkg.m4` and add that directory to the search path.  eg, if `pkg-config` installed `$HOME/share/aclocal/pkg.m4`, you should run `autoreconf -I$HOME/share/aclocal`

There is actually a large school of thought that says that the best way to use pkg-config with the autotools is to not use it.  If you look through the autoconf  mailing list archive, you will see this debated ad-nauseum.   Be aware that many people do recommend avoiding it completely.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the homebrew people decided this wasn't their problem and swept it into a warning. super frustrating since no one will see since no one is using homebrew or automake and expecting to have to dig deep into the details of what is wrong. [Here's the link.](https://github.com/wanderview/servo/commit/cb72a94e1bda324d6e5ae3348f4a0ad4af30d1f6)