# PKG_CHECK_MODULES macro not properly expanding, while i do have pkg-config installed and working

Tags: c, configure, automake, openbox

BEFORE YOU LINK TO: [Using the pkg-config macro PKG_CHECK_MODULES failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578181/using-the-pkg-config-macro-pkg-check-modules-failing)

this does not solve my solution. i do have pkg-config installed. when i type `aclocal --print`, the first thing it gives is `main::scan_file() called too early to check prototype at /usr/local/bin/aclocal line 618`. it does that too in `./bootstrap`.
then it gives the directory `/usr/local/share/aclocal`

for one or another reason, the macro still doesnt work. i am on Artix linux (an Arch like distro), with automake 1.16.2-3 and pkg-conf 1.7.3-1. the output of ./configure, config.log and ./bootstrap are:  https://pastebin.com/NY1GgtFF (`configure`),  https://pastebin.com/iDAUXRv3 (`config.log`) and https://pastebin.com/aRVw00Ex (`bootstrap`)

the macro expansion fails no matter what. do you have any ideas? how would i set the m4_pattern_allow flag? this error occurs both at openbox, and lxterminal. i havent tried any other programs yet where i encounter this error, but i dont think it matters at which program it happens

i really hope i provided enough information, this is my first post, so i hope i did everything right

Comment: So I suppose you are trying to build openbox, but which version or repository?

Comment: @IanAbbott i am cloning https://github.com/danakj/openbox

Comment: All your autoconf/automake stuff is installed under /usr/local. Did you build them yourself? Surely Artix Linux has packages for that sort of stuff?

Comment: @IanAbbott no, its all from the repos from artix.

Comment: I'm just wondering why it's in /usr/local instead of /usr. I've not used Arch for a long while, but surely it hasn't drifted from Linux Standard Base specifications that much.

Comment: @IanAbbott i tried installing them all from source, but i couldn't get m4 installed from source. i also mirrored aclocal in /usr/share and that didn't change anything

Comment: @dcode, no one is suggesting that you install the AutoTools from source.  Quite the opposite, in fact.  But if you *didn't* install them from source, then it is surprising that the binaries being used are in `/usr/local`.  Do you maybe have some of the results of install-from-source attempts still hanging around there?  If so, then that could be part of the problem.

Comment: Does /usr/local/share/aclocal/pkg.m4 exist?  If not, where is `pkg.m4`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger i know, but it gave me the idea, to verify if it was the fault of the way artix compiles the packages. turns out i had pkg-conf, and not pkg-config, very subitle difference. when i installed it form source, it did go to /usr. i switched to void in the mean time, and everything's working like a charm.  it is in the usual location, and included with openbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pkg-conf` is not the same as `pkg-config` — the former is a low-deps reimplementation and does not come with the `pkg.m4` file you need to have the macro installed.

*If* the software you're trying to build comes with a copy of `pkg.m4` bundled in the repository and/or tarball, you may just need to add `-I m4` to the invocation of `aclocal`, otherwise you need to fetch the `pkg.m4` file from a `pkg-config` distribution.

Comment: thanks, i switched to void linux, but the -I m4 was exactly what i needed, because it was bundled!